# updating a branch updates others too in Pycharm

Tags: git, github, pycharm

I have two branches in Pycharm. one is "Master" and second one "des2" in from git hub created locally by:

[image]

"des2" looks ok and synced with github, as supposed to be.

But when I checkout the Master by :

[image]

I see that master also has updated from latest changes in remote branch, and is not different from des2.

I was wondering if I am missing something here,

Thanks,

Comment: What do you mean "updated form latest changes in remote branch"? What remote branch? And what do you expect to be different than des2?

Comment: Your title assumes a cause for the behavior you see. This assumption is false. Updating one branch will **not** automatically update another branch. There is something else going on here.

Comment: Did you execute the `git pull` command to get the changes from the remote branch?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I mean Master, des2, and sgspl are similar. I expect "Master' to be untouched.

Comment: @flaxel no. I need to visually check the changes. so i use compare tool

Comment: Will you show some of the commit history? Feel free to edit out any sensitive information.

Comment: It sounds like `master` and `origin/sgspl` both point to the same commit.